# Не могу отправить Get запрос с токеном на REST API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, cors

Есть рабочий REST API, с Postmen все запросы проходят без проблем, следовательно проблема не в сервере.
На часть запросов требуется токен который выдаётся при авторизации, и проблема в том, что этот токен сервер не считывает, выдаёт ошибку авторизации.

Запросы без авторизации проходят успешно. Политика CORS на сервере соблюдена. Делаю запросы на React JS с помощью axios, помогите решить проблему...

вот мой код на фронте:

```js
const instanse = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://thawing-savannah-74111.herokuapp.com/api',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
  }
});
export const profileAPI = {
  getProfile() {
    return instanse.get("/v2/rest-auth/user/")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.data;
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

В инструменте разработчика выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
xhr.js:177 GET http://thawing-savannah-74111.herokuapp.com/api/v2/rest-auth/user/ 401 (Unauthorized)
at createError (createError.js:16)
at settle (settle.js:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Сам токен в header запроса передаётся: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Postmen header точно такой же, поэтому непонятно в чем проблема (тут токен другой, просто другой пользователь):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В одном случае вы передаете строку, похожую на хэш `md5`, а в другом уже что-то аля `bcrypt`. Мне кажется, тут проблема в отправляемых данных.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас проверю документацию к api, возможно при авторизации он отправил что то другое

Comment: Решил проблему, приходит не тот токен с севака, спасибо icYFTL, что заметил)